# Vim/nvim <BS> and <C-w> delete entire line in (terminal mode from a command) instead of a single character

Tags: vim, vimrc, nvim

I'm creating a mapping which is supposed to navigate to a specific window (call `TEST_WIN`), focus in on the terminal and then delete a single character.

The mapping looks like this:

`noremap ';  :let curWin = win_getid()<CR>:call win_gotoid(TEST_WIN)<CR>A<C-c><C-l><up><BS>`

I have substituted `<BS>` in with `<C-w>` and both of these delete the entire line instead of a single charater/word.

How can I get it to just delete a single word or character?

I should add that when I am controlling the terminal without the command, `<C-w>` and the backspace key on my *Mac* both work as expected. The problem only arises during the command.

Comment: You have `<C-c` there with `noremap`, this means that control+c will have no effect if you have some mapping to it. Please explain what are you trying to do because this mapping looks confusing.

Comment: @Moshe `<C-c>` works perfectly fine. It's the `<BS>` that doesn't work.

Comment: Note there's also a [vi.se] Stack Exchange for questions on Vim, you might want to take a look there as well.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** Answered [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/28344/18609).

Terminal windows are special, you can't just have a mapping use a command to switch to insert mode and then include characters to type in the terminal directly.

Instead, you should call function [`term_sendkeys()`](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#term_sendkeys%28%29) to interact with the terminal.

Something like the following should work:

```
function! TermHistory()
  call win_gotoid(TEST_WIN)
  call term_sendkeys('', "\<C-c>\<C-l>\<Up>\<BS>")
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> '; :call TermHistory()<CR>
```

Comment: @fibranden, this is great, but do you know how it could be done for neovim? the `term_sendkeys` function isn't available for neovim